# Recyclerview item doesn't scroll at bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my xml:

```
<parentLinearLayout>
<toolbar/>
<nestedScrollView>
    <textview>

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/chatting_with"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</nestedScrollView>

<linearLayout>
    <textview>
</linearLayout>
```

The problem is if my recyclerview has 10 items doesnt scroll until the bottom. I mean, this just scroll until the 9th item.

```
  _linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(_linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I also tried:

```
_scrollView.scrollTo(0, _scrollView.getBottom());
_linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(adapter.list.size());
```

Also

```
 _scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

As you can see in this paint I can scroll manually and everything will be good but I want to scroll with code so the user doesnt have to scroll everytime that some item is pushed.

[image]

Comment: If you have 11 items, will it scroll to the 10th item?

Comment: Yes sir. I dont know why

Comment: I think you stripped the code and it has become unreadable for me. Please post the original xml and leave the tags in tact.